# Text breaking out of flexbox container

Tags: css, flexbox

I've been working on learning flexbox for layout and have been unable to figure out why text is not wrapping inside the flex-item. The text is breaking out of the container like this:

[image: Image of broken layout]

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  max-width: 10em;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 12em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.flex-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-item {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="flex-item">
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
        bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with flexbox... A simple google about breaking long words would lead you to the right track

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are no spaces between your text.

The default value of the `word-break` property is `normal`, meaning that a continuous line of text has no line breaks.

For these reasons, your text is not wrapping and overflowing the container.

Add `word-break: break-all` to `.flex-item`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  max-width: 10em;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 12em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.flex-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-item {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  word-break: break-all; /* new */
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="flex-item">
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
        bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From MDN:

> ### [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)
>
> The `word-break` CSS property specifies whether or not the browser
>   should insert line breaks wherever the text would otherwise overflow
>   its content box.
>
> In contrast to `overflow-wrap`, `word-break` will create a break at
>   the exact place where text would otherwise overflow its container
>   (even if putting an entire word on its own line would negate the need
>   for a break).
>
> ---
>
> **Values**
>
> ***`normal`***
>
> Use the default line break rule.
>
> ***`break-all`***
>
> To prevent overflow, word breaks should be inserted between any two
>   characters (excluding Chinese/Japanese/Korean text).
>
> ***`keep-all`***
>
> Word breaks should not be used for Chinese/Japanese/Korean (CJK) text.
>   Non-CJK text behavior is the same as for normal.

---

There's actually another reason – flexbox-specific – why the flex items are overflowing the container. Here's the explanation:

- [Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)

To contain the items (without the need for the text to wrap), you could apply `min-width: 0`, `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` to `.flex-column`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  max-width: 10em;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 12em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.flex-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden; /* new */
  /* overflow: auto; */
  /* min-width: 0; */
}

.flex-item {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="flex-item">
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
        bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```